# Alternatives to forced hot air unit heaters?

Tags: heating

The current heat source in the house a Cadet in wall unit heater in each room. They are really noisy and often emit this "iron left in one place too long" odor from (I presume) scorching dust.

I've seen some wall mounted heaters that look they might be more or less "drop in" replacements - for example the [Stiebel Eltron CNS series](https://www.stiebel-eltron-usa.com/products/cns-e-wall-mounted-convection-heaters).

Is this likely to work or am I chasing a unicorn? Ultimately I'd like to go to a mini-split heat pump system, but that isn't in the budget right now.

[image]

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 1):

When was the last time you cleaned the heaters? Cadet recommends once every 6 months, which I feel is overkill in most cases, but I bet this is something you've never actually done. This should fix the smell at least.

http://cadetheat.com/blog/clean-electric-wall-heater/

Comment: They get cleaned pretty regularly - but the scorching dust smell happens even when the heaters are clean (e.g., within a week of cleaning).

Comment: Is it possible your unit is completely missing one of its filters?

Answer (score 0):

Going from 1 form of electric heat to another sounds like a pipe dream to me , the convection unit not having a fan will not heat the rooms as well especially with such a small area, base board heaters are convection also ever wonder why people change them out the first opportunity they have? save the cost of the convection units and you will be 1/2 way to a mini split system that will not smell and provide AC in the summer.   There are som DIY mini splits out there ~700$ precharged line sets and condenser there smallest unit 12000 BTU might be a way to go small and do it 1 at a time, but a multiple head system would be more efficient.